# Create a Second Dropdown if an Option in a First Dropdwon is Selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm entirely new to HTML/CSS/Javascript and apologize in advance as similar questions have been asked here, but the solutions are far more complex than what I need (and all involve jquery). Since what I need is (hopefully) quite basic, I'm hoping for a simpler, beginner-friendly solution.

My goal: if a user selects a specific option(option "Country Reports") in a dropdown menu ("Dropdown1" , then a second, separate (i.e. not sub-menu), dropdown ("Dropdown2") appears in a predetermined location (i.e. absolute position).

My current HTML code is:

```
<div id="location1">
     <select name="dropdown1">
          <option value="0">     </option>
          <option value="1">Country Reports</option>
          <option value="2">Current Production Costs</option>
          <option value="3">Most Recent Newsflash</option>
      </select> 
</div>
<div id="location2">
     <select name="dropdown2">
          <option value="0">     </option>
          <option value="1A">Country Report Portugal</option>
          <option value="1B">Country Report Spain</option>
          <option value="1C">Country Report Turkey</option>
      </select> 
 </div>
```

The corresponding CSS code is:

```
#location1
{
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 400px;
width: 250px;
height: 70px;
}
#location2
{
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
left: 400px;
width: 250px;
height: 70px;
}
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything with js if yes show us....else try first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a simple JS Function:

```
 function func(){
    if (document.getElementById("dropdown1").value == "1") {    
        document.getElementById("location2").style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("location2").style.display = 'none';
    }
 }
```

You will need to call the above function on `onchange()` event.

```
<div id="location1">
 <select id="dropdown1" onchange="func()">
      <option value="0">     </option>
      <option value="1">Country Reports</option>
      <option value="2">Current Production Costs</option>
      <option value="3">Most Recent Newsflash</option>
  </select> 
</div>
<div id="location2">
 <select name="dropdown2">
      <option value="0">     </option>
      <option value="1A">Country Report Portugal</option>
      <option value="1B">Country Report Spain</option>
      <option value="1C">Country Report Turkey</option>
  </select> 
 </div>
```

Just set `Display` property of **location 2** to `None` to make it invisible by default.

```
#location1
{
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 400px;
width: 250px;
height: 70px;
}
#location2
{
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
left: 400px;
width: 250px;
height: 70px;
display:none;
}
```